# Query for searching duplicates rows on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, database, duplicates

Need to find the rows with duplicates data in a multiple columns

```
hID     sid    lid    aid    did     shid    soid         date
------------------------------------------------------------------
0       123    jkn    rbr    tm      asd     hjk       10/11/2008
1       563    kjh    jkh    dfsd    we      hjk       11/12/2010
2       131    jklj   jkjk   adsd    vcv     asd       01/01/2012
3       656    hjkh   hjkh   dasda   fas     fads      03/26/2012
4       123    jkn    rbr    tm      asd     hjk       09/09/2012
```

Should be able to return like dis one..

```
hID     sid    lid    aid    did     shid    soid         date
------------------------------------------------------------------
0       123    jkn    rbr    tm      asd     hjk       10/11/2008
4       123    jkn    rbr    tm      asd     hjk       09/09/2012
```

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The query below is much more repetitive than @TimSchmelter's solution, but yields a measurable performance advantage for large tables with relatively few duplicates if you happen to have an index on `sid, lid, aid, did, shid, soid`.

```
SELECT t.* FROM t INNER JOIN (
  SELECT sid, lid, aid, did, shid, soid, COUNT(1) AS count FROM t
  GROUP BY sid, lid, aid, did, shid, soid HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) tt ON t.sid=tt.sid AND t.lid=tt.lid AND t.aid=tt.aid AND t.did=tt.did AND t.shid=tt.shid AND t.soid=tt.soid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `GROUP BY` multiple columns. But since you want to find all duplicates you can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
   hID, sid, lid, aid, did, shid, soid, date
FROM TableName t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM TableName t2
   WHERE t2.hid <> t1.hid
   AND  t2.sid  = t1.sid   
   AND  t2.lid  = t1.lid    
   AND  t2.aid  = t1.aid   
   AND  t2.did  = t2.did
   AND  t2.shid = t2.shid   
   AND  t2.soid = t2.soid
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in all SQL servers I tried ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a098d/2)):

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (sid,lid,aid,did,shid,soid) IN (
    SELECT sid,lid,aid,did,shid,soid
    FROM t
    Group By 1,2,3,4,5,6
    HAVING count(1) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with tempTable as
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by sid, lid, aid, did, shid, soid order by hid asc )  as rowid
from #table)
select *
from tempTable
where rowid>1
```

Comment: this will return the duplicated row only.