# I need to get the whole row for all duplicate entries efficiently

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, count, duplicates

internet! I'm pretty new to SQL and I need to get all the rows with duplicate information in certain fields and have them display right next to their other duplicates (group by duplicates).

For instance, say I have a table with columns:

A,B,C,D,E,F,G

I want to be able to get all entries (the full row) where B, C, D, and E share the same value as another entry and show the duplicates right next to the original entry. **I already have a solution, but it is horribly inefficient. I am trying to improve my running time here**.

My original solution was this:

```
    SELECT TOP 1000 
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G
    FROM tbl_myTable
    WHERE (B+C+D+E+F+G) IN (
        SELECT                                  
            B+C+D+E+F+G                 
        FROM                                    
            tbl_myTable                             
        GROUP BY                                    
            B,C,D,E,F,G                 
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
    )

    ORDER BY B,C,D,E,F,G ASC
```

This gave me the results that I wanted, but it is horrendously slow (took over 15 mins to run). I reworked my solution with a temporary table and shaved the time down to 5 mins of running time using this script:

```
    --Drop the temp table if it exists.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp1

SELECT                              
     B+C+D+E+F+G AS CompareString       
 INTO #Temp1
 FROM tbl_myTable                           
 GROUP BY                                   
 B,C,D,E,F,G                
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

 SELECT TOP 1000 
 A,
 B,
 C,
 D,
 E,
 F,
 G
 FROM tbl_myTable
 WHERE (B+C+D+E+F+G) IN (
     SELECT * FROM #Temp1
 )
 ORDER BY B,C,D,E,F,G ASC
```

Five minutes still seems like a long time. Is there a faster way to do this? I'm new to SQL, so if something I did was not good, let me know! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query for searching duplicates rows on multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356671/query-for-searching-duplicates-rows-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: Google and learn about the EXISTS() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
with cte as (
   SELECT *
      , count(*) over (partition by B, C, D, E, F, G) as cnt
      , dense_rank() over (order by B, C, D, E, F, G) as grp
   FROM STI.[dbo].[tbl_Consignee]
)
select * 
from cte
where cnt > 1
order by grp
```

Essentially, the `dense_rank()` call gives each unique tuple an identifier (so you can put duplicates next to each other with the order by clause) and the count counts the number of rows per group.

Comment: I must say, this ran much faster than LDM Joe's method. Both worked well, but yours is much faster. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Now as a stretch goal, see if you can figure out why. Take a look at the execution plans of each and statistics io. Good hunting!

Answer (score 0):

Without actual data, I have to make a few assumptions here.

First, I assume your lettered fields are all text types, and you are using + to concatenate and not to add numeric values (otherwise A+B+C = 6 when A = 1 B = 2 and C = 3 as well as when A=2 B=3 and C=1, which would not be a match).

Next I'm going to assume there is a key field of some kind on each row that is not represented in your example.  Something like tbl_myTable.MyTableKey bigint IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL.

Assuming all that, I'd try...

```
SELECT
    [BaseTable].MyTableKey AS [Original Record],
    [DupCheckTable].MyTableKey AS [Duplicate Record]
FROM
    tbl_myTable [BaseTable]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_myTable [DupCheckTable] ON 
            [BaseTable].A = [DupCheckTable].A
            AND
            [BaseTable].B = [DupCheckTable].B
            AND
            --... repeat for each actual field
            --AND
            [BaseTable].G = [DupCheckTable].G
            AND
            [BaseTable].MyTableKey  < [DupCheckTable].MyTableKey  --the less than operator prevents you from getting each match twice
WHERE
    [DupCheckTable].MyTableKey IS NOT NULL
```

I think this will run faster because you can use the table key, which is presumably indexed, as part of the join.  Also, you feed any of your (or my) queries to the [Tuning Advisor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to see what it thinks would help in the lines of statistics and indexes.

Comment: I think I should be able to join the original rows to these MyTableKey values to get what I need. Thank you so much!

Comment: I see this is your first question.  If this worked, would you please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it?  We work on [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) here, and I'm trying to earn my street cred.

Comment: Sorry - I'm new. Thanks for telling me.